# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items MVC5(DropDownlist)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**My Modal**

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage ="Max Lenght 20")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20,ErrorMessage ="Max Lenght 20")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name ="Date of Joining")]
    public DateTime Dateofjoin { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<CityModal> City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="City")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }


}
public class CityModal {
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

**DROP DOWN LIST VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, new SelectList(ViewBag.city, "CityId", "CityName"), "Select")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "Please select the City", new { @class = "error" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        using (RegMVCEntities obj = new RegMVCEntities())
        {
            ViewBag.city = obj.tblCities.Select(e => new CityModal
            {

                CityName = e.City,
                CityId = e.ID                    
            }).ToList();
        }
            return View();
    }
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        using (RegMVCEntities obj = new RegMVCEntities())
        {
            var query = (from reg in obj.tblRegistrations
                         join citi in obj.tblCities on reg.CityID equals citi.ID
                         where reg.ID == id
                         select new Employee
                         {
                             ID = reg.ID,
                             Name = reg.Name,
                             Address = reg.Address,
                             Salary = reg.Salary,
                             Dateofjoin = reg.DateOfJoining,
                             Email = reg.Email,
                             CityId = citi.ID,
                             CityName = citi.City
                         }).FirstOrDefault();

            /*var employee = obj.tblRegistrations.Where(m => m.ID == id).Select(e => new Employee {
                ID = e.ID,Name = e.Name, Address = e.Address, Dateofjoin = e.DateOfJoining, Salary = e.Salary, Email = e.Email
            }).FirstOrDefault();*/
            return View(query);
        }                
    }
```

here i have checked that in controller query is having the result and contains CityId but VIEW SHOWING "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items". I think create method is having some trouble that i am not getting. Help needed.

Comment: ViewBag.city gets populated but values aren't there in the dropdown?

Comment: It means the value of `ViewBag.city` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag.city` is set in the GET version of your `Create` action, but I'd imagine you've probably neglected to set it again in the POST version. However, you have posted the code for that. Additionally, it is not set in your `Edit` action, either. That may not have bearing on the current issue, but it will become an issue of its own soon, likely.

In general, the exception is telling you that the `items` param (i.e. the first param to the `SelectList` constructor) is null. Which it will be if `ViewBag.city` is not set in your action. Since it is in your GET version, I can only presume that you're receiving this exception on validation error, when the view is returned again to allow the user to make necessary edits.